# обращение к файлу с таким же названием как значение переменной JS

Tags: javascript

Существует переменная со значением = dveri, и файл с таким же названием = dveri.txt. Можно ли как то вызвать файл используя данную переменную?

Comment: "вызвать файл" - ??

Comment: Я может не корректно выразился. Обратится к файлу, не знаю

Comment: Клиенский `js` на это не способен... Только `nodeJS серверный js`

Comment: А можете написать код, хоть в общих чертах?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с файловой системой понадобится [модуль](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) 'fs', а чтобы прочитать что-то из файла - метод, например синхронный, readFileSync. Также есть асинхронный метод, подробнее в документации. Ссылку прикрепил.

```
const fs = require('fs'); // подключаем модуль

const fileName = 'dveri'; // наша переменная
const data = fs.readFileSync(‘${fileName}.txt’, 'utf-8'); // важно указать кодировку вторым аргументом

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Я подключил этот код в проект, браузер ругается: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @NothingHappen, если Вы пытаетесь сделать это в браузере, то у Вас не получится. Как и сказали выше в комментариях: клиентский js на это не способен